# Why would one build a spacecraft out of a gigantic mutated rat?

Tags: mythical-creatures, mutation

I’m working on a small story, where all the stars in the cosmos have turned into the size of tiny rats and rats have turned into the size of gigantic suns. This happened due to some sort of unknown mutation, not even humans know exactly why this happened.

Years went by, and dead rats the size of suns became a great way of keeping warm: now that suns weren’t as big as they usually were. Man kind are looking to conquer space, after thousands of years living inside giant rats—they decide to build spacecrafts out of these huge rats!

But why on Earth would they wish to build spacecrafts out of rats? I’d really like for it to be part of the story, but I need some reasons as to why they choose to build spacecrafts out of dead gigantic rats rather than gathering the raw materials normally used to make spacecrafts.

Comment: Probably because they're used to using giant rats for everything else?

Comment: Dead rat the size of the sun on earth would destroy the earth. Sun is 110 times larger than our planet.

Comment: They even eat Ratatouille...

Comment: The rats are actually small, it’s just that they’re big. Therefore, they don’t destroy the planet.

Comment: Relevant xkcd for what happens to creatures the size of planets, though this is [a mole of moles](https://what-if.xkcd.com/4/)

Comment: @D.Ataro a dead rat the size of the sun would be larger than the earth, it would tear the planet apart through gravity alone, dead or not.

Comment: Because they don't like the crew?

Answer (score 4):

I am thinking this entire scenario is either a Kafka-esque bizarre commentary or a trolling of the worldbuilding site.  Negative votes suggest people think the latter.  I am going to assume the former.

I am assuming that you will introduce the scenario without a lot of exposition: just the plain facts about the rats and the stars.  From there you can just have the people build things out of rats.  No reason not to have them wear rats for clothes too; ratsuits.  Eating rats.  Mating with rats.  The whole rat thing.

I really hope there is a clever twist when you write it.

Comment: rats ... star ... hmm. I could see a Kafka type story like James and the Giant Peach. I think the facts or science are irrelevant in this case though. If the OP hasn't figured out how to transform his ugly duckling (the rat-ship) into a swan, his post would be better suited for a different Stack Exchange site.

Comment: I had never perceived how Kafkaesque Giant Peach is but it certainly is.  Starting with the first page when James' parents are killed and eaten by a rhinoceros.